# Function return 'None' Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, reverse

Hi i am learning python on my own.

Task:
Reverse word without affecting special characters

Example "abcd efgh" => "dcba hgfe"
Example "a1bcd efg!h" => "d1cba hgf!e"

My problem: the function return None

Then i added this line:
`return reverse_text` but it still return None

Can anyone show me where is my mistake is, please?

My code:

```
from string import punctuation
from string import digits


def reverse_text(str_smpl):
    sp = set.union(set(punctuation), set(digits))
    reverse_text.lst = []
    for word in str_smpl.split(' '):
        letters = [c for c in word if c not in sp]
        for c in word:
            if c not in sp:
                reverse_text.lst.append(letters.pop())
                continue
            else:
                reverse_text.lst.append(c)
        reverse_text.lst.append(' ')
    return reverse_text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cases = [
        ("abcd efgh", "dcba hgfe"),
        ("a1bcd efg!h", "d1cba hgf!e"),
        ("", "")
    ]

    for text, reversed_text in cases:
        assert reverse_text(str_smpl) == reversed_text

    reverse_text(input('Input string '))
    print("".join(reverse_text.lst))
```

Comment: injecting the list is not so pythonic. try to return the reordered list `return reverse_text.lst`

Comment: Why does `reverse_text` attach a list to itself before returning itself, rather than just returning a list?

Comment: What's the purpose of `reverse_text.lst`?

Comment: One hint is that your function doesn't return `None` --- it returns itself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are returning `reverse_text` which is the name of the function, so the function is returning a reference to itself (not what you want!).

Assigning properties to functions like you have with `reverse_text.lst` is not something I have really come across in Python and I would suggest you just use a new local variable named something like `reversed_text_list` to avoid confusion.

I think you also want to join the characters in the list together and return a string.

The following seems to be doing what I think you are trying to do:

```
def reverse_text(str_smpl):
    sp = set.union(set(punctuation), set(digits))
    reversed_text_list = []
    for word in str_smpl.split(' '):
        letters = [c for c in word if c not in sp]
        for c in word:
            if c not in sp:
                reversed_text_list.append(letters.pop())
                continue
            else:
                reversed_text_list.append(c)
        reversed_text_list.append(' ')
        reversed_text = ''.join(reversed_text_list)
    return reversed_text
```

Answer (score 0):

It returned error because you had defined `reverse_text.lst` but returned only `reverse_text`, the following code will work:-

```py
from string import punctuation
from string import digits


def reverse_text(str_smpl):
    sp = set.union(set(punctuation), set(digits))
    lst = []

    for word in str_smpl.split(' '):
        letters = [c for c in word if c not in sp]

        for c in word:
            if c not in sp:
                lst.append(letters.pop())
                continue
            else:
                lst.append(c)

        lst.append(' ')

    return "".join(lst[:len(lst)-1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cases = [
        ("abcd efgh", "dcba hgfe"),
        ("a1bcd efg!h", "d1cba hgf!e"),
        ("", "")
    ]

    for text, reversed_text in cases:
        assert reverse_text(text) == reversed_text

    print(reverse_text(input('Input string ')))
```

Comment: Firstly, you removed line with assert.
Now programm doesn't work correct cuz line 16 `lst.append(' ')`

Comment: Your `assert` wasn't in the function, instead it was in the `if` clause